# Screen resize moves svg around?

Tags: html, css, svg, resize, position

Im using a "wave" **svg** but its moving around if i **resize** the screen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#block {
  height: 800px;
  background:green;
}

#first, #second {
  height: 400px;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}

#first {
  background:red;
}

#second {
  background:blue;
}

#svgBox {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  top:-170px;
}

.wave {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="svgBox">
      <svg class="wave" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="blue" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,64L60,96C120,128,240,192,360,213.3C480,235,600,213,720,197.3C840,181,960,171,1080,186.7C1200,203,1320,245,1380,266.7L1440,288L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to **fix** this issue? I want that if you **resize** the screen, that the svg is still on the right place.

**Issue:** If you resize the screen, the svg will move up or down

Comment: Your CSS assumes that the SVG will be 170px in height (hence the `top: -170px`) but makes absolutely no effort to force that size. So when the window gets smaller, the SVG scales and "moves".

Comment: Since the width of the svg is 100vw I would use `top: -22vw`

Answer (score 1):

The right solution would be:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0;
}

#block {
  height: 800px;
  background:green;
}

#first, #second {
  height: 400px;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}

#first {
  background:red;
}

#second {
  background:blue;
}

.wave {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height:auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="block">
  <div id="first">
    <svg class="wave" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="blue" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,64L60,96C120,128,240,192,360,213.3C480,235,600,213,720,197.3C840,181,960,171,1080,186.7C1200,203,1320,245,1380,266.7L1440,288L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="second"></div>
</section>
```